# Why covariance values are different in R and ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster, r, statistics

I've calculated covariance between 7 rasters using R and ArcGIS. It gives me different results. Each times covariance values from R are approximately 1.874 times higher than ArcGIS values.

R - package `raster`, function `layerStats(stack, 'cov', na.rm=TRUE)`
[image]

ArcGIS - Band Collection Statistics tool (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000q3000000)
[image]

Why covariance values are different in R and ArcGIS?

Comment: How do the means reported by ArcGIS compare to those reported by `R`?

Comment: The means are identical.

Comment: If `na.rm=TRUE`, `N` is equal to `(n - cellStats(r, stat = "countNA") - asSample)`. How ArcGIS manages the missing values?

Comment: What data type are the rasters (ints, floats, ... how many bytes)?  How many cells do they have?  Since the means are reported correctly, the problem is probably not related to NoData values, but it might still be of interest to know how many NoData values they have, too. Are there any cells where some of the rasters have NoData and others do have data?

Comment: upvoting the question... wish someone had an answer

Answer (score 5):

Create some simple test rasters in R:

```
> m=matrix(1:9,3,3)
> m2 = matrix(c(9,2,3,4,1,5,6,8,7),3,3)
```

Then we can trivially compute the covariance between these matrices:

```
> cov(c(m),c(m2))
[1] 2.125
```

and I would wager doing the computation by hand would get the same result. What does `layerStats` do?

```
> D = stack(raster(m),raster(m2))

> layerStats(D, "cov", na.rm=TRUE)
$covariance
        layer.1 layer.2
layer.1   7.500   2.125
layer.2   2.125   7.500
```

There's the same 2.125 in the cross-correlation.

Now try with an NA in there:

```
> m[2,2]=NA
> cov(c(m),c(m2),use="complete.obs")
[1] 2.428571
> D = stack(raster(m),raster(m2))
> layerStats(D, "cov", na.rm=TRUE)
$covariance
         layer.1  layer.2
layer.1 8.571429 2.428571
layer.2 2.428571 7.500000
```

Again, `cov` agrees with `layerStats` if we remove the `NA` value.

So what does ArcGIS do in each of these situations? Save the `D`, import to ArcGIS, and find out...

**EDIT**

**The results from ArcGIS:**

Raster m and m2:

[image]

Raster with an NA and m2:

[image]

[Now, the question is - Which way of calculating covariance between rasters is correct?]

Comment: +1 even though it's only half an answer, because it shows exactly the right way to approach the question: test the software on simple data with known results.

Comment: The covariance and correlation are **unchanged** in ArcGIS even with a missing value? You've used the right second layer because I can see STD of layer 2 is `sqrt(var(c(1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9))`. How many missing values can you add to layer 2 before it changes? Does it just copy layer 1 to layer 2 if missing in layer 2? What does the docs say?